# Why is Google Maps JavaScript API (v3) not using canvas?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, canvas, google-maps-api-3

Why is the Google Maps JavasScript API using DIVs to render everything? This seems to be a performance problem on iOS. Furthermore why is the official Google Maps using a canvas?

I have been trying to google the answer for this question for a while now. Seems like the Google Maps API does not support canvas rendering of the map at all. It insist on using and transforming divs. Meanwhile if I go to the official Google Maps application, it does use a canvas for map rendering.

Is there a way to render everything on canvas or what am I missing here?

Edit: **My own answer in comments. In short, canvas rendering simply does not exist for the public Google Maps JavaScript API (v3). Official Google Maps uses a Google Experiment called MapsGL, which is not publicly available yet. As to why Google Maps API does not support canvas - my best guess is that by using hardware accelerated div-system was the only option at the time the public API was made.**

Comment: Have you tried to ask in their [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/maps)?

Comment: Seems like canvas rendering for Google Maps API simply does not exist. There is a Google Experiment called MapsGL, which the current official Google Maps uses for canvas rendering, but I do not think it is publicly available.